# Class library reference for Include extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am reading a tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

There I found some code like

```
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
    .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
```

I like to understand the `.Include` method. Where is the reference? (I am expecting something like class library reference)

Comment: [EF Eager Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. I just wanted to know the namespace, class and the method signature, overload, such information. Sorry if I am too confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To better understand how it’s working, let’s take these sample Entity classes:

```
 public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

public class StudentAddress 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentAddressDetail> StudentAddressDetails { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**Eager Loading**

The Eager Loading function is useful when you want to load the main Entity (or Entity collection) together with its related entities right from the start, possibly using a single query command. In order to use that you need to use the `Include()` method in the following way:

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    // Loads the students AND all related StudentAddress using Eager Loading
    IList<Student> sList = ctx.Students.Include(s => s.StudentAddress).ToList<Student>();
    Student s = sList[0];
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: *If you can’t find the `Include()` method, check that you added the `System.Data.Entity` namespace.*

You can also use Eager Loading to load nested, multi-level properties. For example, we could load the StudentAddressDetails collection property of each StudentAddress item (cfr. the StudentAddress class definition above) in the following way:

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
    // Loads the students AND all related StudentAddress AND all related StudentAddressDetails using Eager Loading
    IList<Student> sList = ctx.Students.Include(s => s.StudentAddress.StudentAddressDetails).ToList<Student>();
    Student s = sList[0];
}
```

This has been well explained [here](http://www.ryadel.com/en/enable-or-disable-lazyloading-in-entity-framework/). The answer above is an extract from this post:

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I just wanted to know the namespace, class and the method signature, overload, such information. Sorry if I am too confusing.

Comment: @MuthuVel the namespace is `System.Data.Entity` use include and `right click on that and go to definition` you will get your answer. If you read my answer you can get everything you required.

Comment: Thanks Manish. You are correct. The fact is, I dont know to right click and find the definition. I would always google and go to the msdn site. I expected some link like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx. But your comment is the answer to  my question. I mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY This content is [not your own](http://www.ryadel.com/en/enable-or-disable-lazyloading-in-entity-framework/), and you have not provided attribution for the source. This is bad. Please review your other posts and correct them as appropriate.

Comment: @spender thanks for pointing out my mistake, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `using System.Data.Entity;` in your file.